Namespace 'puresnmp_plugins.mpm' did not contain a plugin with identifier 0. Known identifiers: []. See the 'puresnmp' documentation on plugins
    from puresnmp import Client, ObjectIdentifier as oid, credentials
    oids = [oid('.1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.3.3.1.3.1'),  # upsInputVoltage
                oid('.1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.3.3.1.2.1'),  # input frequency.
                oid('.1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.5.0'),  # battery voltage.
                oid('.1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.7.0'),  # UPS Battery temperature
                oid('.1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.2.4.0'),  # Battery capacity
                oid('.1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.4.4.1.2.1'),  # upsOutputVoltage
                oid('.1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.4.2.0'),  # output frequency
                oid('.1.3.6.1.2.1.33.1.4.4.1.5.1')  # ups load percentage
                ]
    client = Client('172.16.2.101', credentials.V1("public"), port=161)
    result1 = client.multiget(oids)
    x = run(result1)
    result = [0] * len(oids)
    for j in range(len(oids)):
        xx = bytes(x[j])
    result[j] = int.from_bytes(xx[2:], byteorder="big", signed=True)

I'm using SNMPv1 only as I want to fetch data only from SNMP agent. When I'm running the above code through PyCharm IDE, it's working normal. After converting it into .exe file using Pyinstaller, it's giving above puresnmp plugin error.

Namespace 'puresnmp_plugins.mpm' did not contain a plugin with identifier 0. Known identifiers: []. See the 'puresnmp' documentation on plugins.".

I followed (https://github.com/exhuma/puresnmp/issues/117solution) and installed typing-extensions package but no use.
